# Remove line break for csv import

Tags: php

I have a text field in the database with datatype also as text. It holds comments and stuff. Now when I read this and export in a csv if it finds a new line in that comment such as

```
This is a comment

This is another line
```

The csv import show "This is another line" in next line and thus mess up my data.

So far I have tried str_replace(), trim(). Still don't seem to do anything. I have looked for similar answers in stackoverflow but couldn't find one that suits my problem

Thanks

Comment: How are you exporting to csv to begin with? CSV should have no trouble with embedded line breaks if the field is properly enclosed with quotes.

Comment: Can you preprocess the input, like run it though `sed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you searching for in the str_replace function? You should be able to search for "\r" and or "\n" the the given string. Examples are documented in the PHP str_replace documentation. Example links below:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#example-4450

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#97374

Comment: str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '', $string) worked for me Thanks.. I was searcing for \r\n and \n before and it didn't worked but i was not searching for them all at once like I should have been and I guess that was the reason my line was breaking up

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your newlines to printf-style strings, you can avoid this problem.

```
<?php

$t='This is a comment

This is another line
';

print str_replace("\n","\\n",$t);
```

Output:

```
This is a comment\n\nThis is another line\n
```

Also look in to [htmlspecialchars()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  You need to protect other characters that could break your CSV.

Lastly, have a close look at [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to see if it'll do what you need.  Might be better to use builtins than to roll your own.